# How to print result from sql query with month name

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL query which retrieving count with month.

Ex :

```
 January - 5
 February - 2 so on.
```

What I need to know is, if there are no record for particular month, how to print that month and display its count as 0.

This is my query:

```
select 
    DATETNAME(MONTH, c.postTime) as Month, COUNT(c.regNo) as Count
from 
    Company c
where
    DATENAME(YEAR, c.postTime) = 2015
group by 
    c.postTime
```

This query returns these results:

```
MONTH   | Count
-----------------
July    | 2
August  | 1
```

The result I'm looking for should be:

```
MONTH   | Count
-----------------
January | 0
February| 0
March   | 0
April   | 0
May     | 0
June    | 0
July    | 2
August  | 1
.
.
.

so on...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT m.Name, COUNT(COALESCE(c.regNo, 0)) as Count
FROM
(
VALUES ('Janurary'), ('February'), ('March'),
      ('April'),    ('May'),      ('June'),
      ('July'),     ('August'),   ('September'),
      ('October'),  ('November'), ('December')
) AS m(Name)
LEFT JOIN Company c ON DATETNAME(MONTH, c.postTime) = m.Name
AND DATENAME(YEAR, c.postTime) = 2015
GROUP BY m.Name;
```

Use And instead of "Where" keyword. Then It's working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to drive them from anchor query where all the months' list are written explicitly, then `left join` your table `company`:

```
SELECT m.Name, COUNT(COALESCE(c.regNo, 0)) as Count
FROM
(
   VALUES ('Janurary'), ('February'), ('March'),
          ('April'),    ('May'),      ('June'),
          ('July'),     ('August'),   ('September'),
          ('October'),  ('November'), ('December')
) AS m(Name)
LEFT JOIN Company c ON DATETNAME(MONTH, c.postTime) = m.Name
WHERE DATENAME(YEAR, c.postTime) = 2015
GROUP BY m.Name;
```

If the table `company` doesn't have any particular month, it will be shown with count 0.

---

You can also use a recursive CTE to generate numbers from 1 to 12 and cast these integers to month names:

```
;WITH CTE 
AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE n < 12
), Months
AS
(
    SELECT DATENAME(Month, 
                    DATEADD(Month, 
                            n-1, 
                            CAST('2015-01-01' AS datetime)))  AS Name
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT m.Name, COUNT(COALESCE(c.regNo, 0)) as Count
FROM Months AS m
LEFT JOIN Company c ON DATETNAME(MONTH, c.postTime) = m.Name
WHERE DATENAME(YEAR, c.postTime) = 2015
GROUP BY m.Name;
```

Comment: It'll give an error like "Column m.Name is invalid  in the select list because it is not contained in either aggregation function or the Group By clause"

Comment: @SumuduDeZoysa - Sorry my fault, please try the updated query, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Mahmoud. your answer is correct when I change "Where" keyword to "AND". Thanks a lot :)